# Page move to the left on scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've designed the webpage for restaurant where I'm making extra money while studying. It's mostly done, but I have one bug that I can't fix and find answer on Google. The problem is that, when I click on link in menu bar page is scrolling to the div, but it moves whole page to the left. When I scroll to the bottom of the page or reload, it backs to normal. It only happens when scrolling down (if you are in "Jak dojechać" div and click on menu it won't happen).
The page is divided into divs with content with css:

```
div.test {
    width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    position: sticky;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap:  wrap;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Here's the link for the webpage
https://broburgerzory.pl/

Comment: i don't have that behaviour on my screen!!

Comment: can you provide a gif or picture ?

Comment: Try to remove all the animations of the page, i didn't find it the cause of it. So, go adding one by one and try to find what is causing it..